# Third party Jar pom.xml

Tags: java, docker, maven, gradle

We have a third party jar sitting in internal maven artifactory. We have to wrap it as docker image and persist in a docker registry. We have CI process in place to build a maven project and wrap it with docker and deploy it. But in this case, there is no additional java build process required as its a runnable 3rd party jar.

I know as part of CI step, we can do this and then continue to docker build

```
mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=<org:artifact:version> -DoutputDirectory=<Path>/target
```

But this needs a custom CI step just to accommodate this. **Question**: Is there anyway that we can avoid this special CI step, probably by using a dummy wrapper pom.xml to download the thirdparty jar and make it as the build output.

Not married to maven, it can be gradle too.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue correctly. Do you want to just wrap a 3rd-party jar in its own container, or is it your project dependency that should be added to the project during fhe build?

Comment: The former. It's not a dependency, it's the final app jar. But I don't want to tweak my CI step for this special case. I want it to disguise like normal build process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "copy" part seems to be trivial: you just need to add corresponding `maven-dependency-plugin` configuration to `pom.xml` and assign proper lifecycle phase to `copy` goal, for example, the configuration below:

```xml
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <id>copy</id>
   <goals>
    <goal>copy</goal>
   </goals>
   <phase>prepare-package</phase>
   <configuration>
    <artifactItems>
     <artifactItem>
      <groupId>tld.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
      <version>version</version>
      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
      <destFileName>copy-of-artifact.jar</destFileName>
     </artifactItem>
    </artifactItems>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

causes maven to copy required jar into target directory during build lifecycle.

As regards to "mark third party jar as the build output" part, there are a couple of options:

I. basically, you may `unpack` third party jar into classes directory and ask `maven-jar-plugin` do not create manifest:

```xml
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
 <configuration>
  <useDefaultManifestFile>true</useDefaultManifestFile>
 </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <id>unpack</id>
   <goals>
    <goal>unpack</goal>
   </goals>
   <phase>prepare-package</phase>
   <configuration>
    <artifactItems>
     <artifactItem>
      <groupId>tld.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
      <version>version</version>
      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
     </artifactItem>
    </artifactItems>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

II. another option is to trick maven build via disabling `maven-jar-plugin` and modifying project's state using `gmavenplus-plugin`:

```xml
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <id>default-jar</id>
   <phase>none</phase>
  </execution>
 </executions>
 <configuration>
  <skip>true</skip>
 </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <id>copy</id>
   <goals>
    <goal>copy</goal>
   </goals>
   <phase>prepare-package</phase>
   <configuration>
    <artifactItems>
     <artifactItem>
      <groupId>tld.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
      <version>version</version>
      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
      <destFileName>${project.build.finalName}.jar</destFileName>
     </artifactItem>
    </artifactItems>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
 <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.13.1</version>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <phase>package</phase>
   <goals>
    <goal>execute</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <bindAllProjectProperties>true</bindAllProjectProperties>
    <scripts>
     <script><![CDATA[
project.artifact.file = new File("${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar")
  ]]></script>
    </scripts>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
   <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.9</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the issue correctly, you want to wrap a 3-rd party jar in its own container within a Maven build.

So it would not be a completely dummy `pom.xml`, but a small Maven project that:

- has the mentioned jar as a dependency
- and either uses [`maven-assembly-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) with an assembly descriptor in `src/assembly` to put that jar into `target` for further usage
- or builds and pushes an image by itself using, say, [`jib-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin).

That project could be both an independent one, or you can include the same into your existing project if you want.